# Get associative array using preg_split

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have 2 issues with my below regex:

1) The output shows 2 extra (blank) element at the beginning and end (can't use PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY as isbn can be empty).

2) Is it possible to get associative array from this? I mean I want output in the form of $output = array("title" => "Book1", "writer" => "writer1", "isbn" => "1234") in this format.

```
$val = "[title]Book1[/title][writer]Writer1[/writer][isbn]1234[/isbn]";
$pattern = '/\[title](.*?)\[\/title].*?\[writer](.*?)\[\/writer].*?\[isbn](.*?)\[\/isbn]/i';
$allparams = preg_split($pattern, $val, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => Book1 [2] => Writer1 [3] => 1234 [4] => )
```

Comment: So why are you using `preg_split` instead of `preg_match` for a matching job?

Comment: I need those 3 elements separately in an array. Can preg_match achive that?

Comment: `preg_split` isn't the right function to do that, you need to use `preg_match` with named captures and to filter numeric keys from the result array.

Comment: Also... the pattern can begin and end with any character, such as ~ or # or =. Use something other than / so you don't have to escape / every time you use it in the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_split` isn't the way to go, use `preg_match` (or `preg_match_all` if your want several results from a single string):

```
$pattern = '~
    \[title]  (?<title>  [^[]+ ) \[/title]  .*?
    \[writer] (?<writer> [^[]+ ) \[/writer] .*?
    \[isbn]   (?<isbn>   [^[]+ ) \[/isbn]
~sx';

if (preg_match($pattern, $yourtext, $m)) {
    echo 'title:  ' . $m['title']  . PHP_EOL
       . 'writer: ' . $m['writer'] . PHP_EOL
       . 'isbn:   ' . $m['isbn']   . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The `s` flag allows the dot to match newlines, and the `x` flag ignores whitespaces in the pattern.

Note that you can filter numeric keys since PHP 5.6 like this (not tested):

```
$result = array_filter($m, function ($k) { return !is_numeric($k); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

If you don't have PHP >= 5.6, a simple `foreach` loop can do the job:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($m as $k=>$v) {
    if (is_numeric($k) || empty($v)) continue;
    $result[$k] = $v;
}
```

Comment: wow ..I wasn't aware of such regex syntax. Thanks a lot. One last thing, is it possible to make it work even if some elements are missing (for example no [writer][/writer] block)? So I mean all three elements should be optional, "if found" basis.

Comment: @AbdFahim: You can always enclose each bbcode tag in an optional group, like this `(?:\[title]...\[/title] .*?)?` etc., but don't forget to take care that at least one group exists (perhaps you can start the pattern with a lookahead assertion, something like `(?=\[)` or `(?=\[(?:title|writer|isbn)])`) or more simple you check if `$m` doesn't only contain empty items.

Answer (score 1):

something like that will do the trick, even if it's not the best way I think...

```
$a = "/\[(.*)\](.*)\[\/.*\]/U";
$val = "[title]Book1[/title][writer]Writer1[/writer][isbn]1234[/isbn]";
$array = json_decode('{'.substr(preg_replace($a, ',"$1":"$2"', $val), 1).'}');
```

BTW, this one find every `[TAG]` and put it in the array (whenever how many tag you use).
Be careful, as it use JSON, it may have some problem with `"` or unexpected string not in `[tag]string[/tag]` pattern.

Comment: This is intelligent, and serves the purpose. Thanks, I learned something today. This time I'll go with Casimir's solution though.